# modify collection result in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Now I have a returned collection data like:

```
[{'category':1,
     'title':"Current Company", 
     'people':{"count":2,                
             "keyword":"",
             "executiveInfos":[{"name":"Darren Suomi", 
                                "title":"Global Vice President of Sales",
                                "companyId":2867257,
                                "employmentId":10993552,
                                "executiveId":10152454,
                             "imageUrl":"https://d1tzls7byl3ryp.cloudfront.net/iv/profileImages/executiveImage/321446",
                                "count":0,
                                "executiveConnectionImageUrls":[],
                                "trackedByWatchlists":[],
                                "employmentType":0},
                               {"name":"Gregory  Gunn",
                                "title":"Vice President of Business Development",
                                "companyId":2867257,
                                "employmentId":9240823,
                                "executiveId":9049103,
                                "imageUrl":"https://d1tzls7byl3ryp.cloudfront.net/iv/profileImages/executiveImage/292479",
                                "count":0,
                                "executiveConnectionImageUrls":[],
                                "trackedByWatchlists":[],
                                "employmentType":0}]***}
     },
{'category': 2, 
 'title':"Former Company",
 'people':{"count":0,
         "finance":0,
         "otherFunction":0,
         "keyword":"",
         "executiveInfos":[]}
},
{'category': 4,
 'title':"Family Tree Company",
 'people':{"count":0,
         "keyword":"",
         "executiveInfos":[]}
 }
]
```

In the data, it has 3 categories, in each category it has an attribute named people, now I
want to list the executiveInfos of people in each category, my listview is:

```
var PeopleListView =  Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.bucketContent'),
    initialize:  function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    }
        render: function() {
           this.collection.each( function( $model) {                
            var itemview = new PeopleItemView({model : $model});                    
            this.$el.prepend(itemview.render().el);  

        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});
```

what should I do? thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to iterate over the models in the collection, then for each of those, iterate over `model.people.executiveInfos`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `PeopleItemView` does, it is difficult to give you a proper answer.  However, assuming that you are implementing this view correctly, you would need to ensure that you are properly passing over all of the model attributes to your template.

For example, assuming that the `PeopleItemView` view looks something like this:

```
var PeopleItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  this.template = JST["the_template_name"];
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
  }
});
```

You could then iterate through `executiveInfos` through the template itself.  In Handlebars this would look like:

```
{{#each people.executiveInfos}}
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <span>{{title}}</span>
    <span>{{companyId}}</span>
    <span>{{employmentId}}</span>
    <span>{{executiveId}}</span>
    ...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Could I change the returned collection that using parse function to return only the executiveInfos in each category?

Comment: Definitely! If you are only concerned with the executiveInfos field then you could absolutely do that.